# Reduce database calls for php web shop

Tags: php, oop, caching

I'm looking for a way to prevent repeated calls to the database if the item in question has already been loaded previously. The reason is that we have a lot of different areas that show popular items, latest releases, top rated etc. and sometimes it happens that one item appears in multiple lists on the same page.

I wonder if it's possible to save the object instance in a static array associated with the class and then check if the data is actually in there yet, but then how do I point the new instance to the existing one?

Here's a draft of my idea:

```
 $baseball = new Item($idOfTheBaseballItem);  
 $baseballAgain = new Item($idOfTheBaseballItem);

 class Item 
 {  
      static $arrItems = array();  

      function __construct($id) {
           if(in_array($id, self::arrItems)){
               // Point this instance to the object in self::arrItems[$id]
               // But how?
          }
          else {
              // Call the database  

              self::arrItems[id] = $this;
          }
      }
 }
```

If you have any other ideas or you just think I'm totally nuts, let me know.

Comment: As you said it's popular items, i Imagine it's the same for all users, right? Then, you can cache it in XML or something, and your page will read from the XML, which is much faster than querying the DB. You can schedule how often your app will update the XML.

Comment: Hi Andre, yes most of the lists are indeed the same for all users. I wasn't aware that reading from a file is faster than querying the database (it's MSSQL!) I'll definitely give it a try.

Comment: Yes, it's faster because the file will be organized in the order you want them displayed, uses less memory, and you can move your database to another server without performance loss. BTW, I'll also study this memcache class @Khez said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that static variables only exist in the page they were created, meaning 2 users that load the same page and get served the same script still exist as 2 different memory spaces.

You should consider caching results, take a look at [code igniter database caching](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html)

What you are trying to achieve is similar to a singleton factory

```
$baseball = getItem($idOfTheBaseballItem);  
$baseballAgain =getItem($idOfTheBaseballItem);

function getItem($id){
    static $items=array();
    if(!isset($items[$id])$items[$id]=new Item($id);
    return $items[$id];
}

class Item{  
    // this stays the same
}
```

P.S. Also take a look at [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php). A very simple way to remove database load is to create a /cache/ directory and save database results there for a few minutes or until you deem the data old (this can be done in a number of ways, but most approaches are time based)

Comment: Thanks for your straightforward solution. Also cheers for pointing me back to memcache, I'm going to finally look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly replace "this" in constructor. Instead, prepare a static function like "getById($id)" that returns object from list.
And as stated above: this will work only per page load.